# android: bugged Toolbar in secondary activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement a toolbar in my second activity. But i'm having troubles with it.

**Activity.java (AddActivity)**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    initToolbar();
    Button close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2222);
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void initToolbar(){
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.add_app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_navigation_close);

}
}
```

**app_bar file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/generic_toolbar"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**activity layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_add"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.daveslab.wideview.AddActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/add_app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="129dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2222" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**problems:**
-the notification bar it white
-the app bar has no shadows
-it doesn't work as a toolbar

I've also tryed(main toolbar layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"              
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.daveslab.wideview.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_create_white_48px" />

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i added a new activity with the toolbar aready installed in the correct way (only in AndroidStudio 2.1+)